# How to add custom data attribute to serialize params in Gridster.js?

Tags: jquery, html, widget, gridster

I am using Gridster.js with JQuery to design a widget container. So I want to use serialized_params property of Gridster.js to save some other attributes(owner and company) of added widgets. I tried as below but it does not see the data attributes which I added.

Note:(size_x and size_y attributes work correct.)

Please tell me how to do that?

```
function addWidget() {

$(".gridster ul").gridster({
    widget_margins : [ 10, 10 ],
    widget_base_dimensions : [ 140, 140 ],
    serialize_params : function($w, wgd) {
        return {
            id : $w.attr('id'),
            col : wgd.col,
            row : wgd.row,
            size_x : wgd.size_x,
            size_y : wgd.size_y,
            classes : $w.attr('class'),
            styles : $w.attr('style'),
            owner : wgd.owner,
            company :wgd.company
        };
    }
});

var gridster = $(".gridster ul").gridster().data('gridster');

var widgetHtml = '<li class= "orange" data-row="2" data-col="6" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="2" data-owner="omertasci" data-company="XYZ">'
        + '<i class="fa fa-times"></i>'
        + '<h1 style="padding-top: 0em ! important;">New Widget</h1>'
        + '<script> '
        + '$(function() { $(".fa-times").on("click", function() { var indexOfLi = $(this).parent().index(); removeWidget(indexOfLi);}   );  });'
        + '</script>' + '</li>';

gridster.add_widget(widgetHtml, 2, 1);
serializedGridster = gridster.serialize();
}
```

Result of serialized widget:

```
 {classes:"orange gs-w"
  col:5
  id:undefined
  row:1
  size_x:2
  size_y:1
  styles:"display: list-item; opacity: 0;"}
```

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

I overcame this by implemeting my own serialize function.

```
function serializeGridster() {

    var serializeJsonArr = new Array();

    $(".gridster ul li").each(function(i) {

       var serializeJson = {};

       var id = $(this).attr('id');
       var classes = $(this).attr('class');
       var style = $(this).attr('style');
       var owner= $(this).attr('data-owner');
       var company= $(this).attr('data-company');
       var row = $(this).attr('data-row');
       var col = $(this).attr('data-col');
       var sizex = $(this).attr('data-sizex');
       var sizey = $(this).attr('data-sizey');

       serializeJson["id"] = id;
       serializeJson["classes"] = classes;
       serializeJson["style"] = style;
       serializeJson["owner"] = owner;
       serializeJson["company"] = company;
       serializeJson["row"] = row;
       serializeJson["col"] = col;
       serializeJson["sizex"] = sizex;
       serializeJson["sizey"] = sizey;

       serializeJsonArr.push(serializeJson);
   });

  // console.log(serializeJsonArr);
  return serializeJsonArr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is the jQuery [`data()`](https://api.jquery.com/data/) method:

```
$(".gridster ul").gridster({
    widget_margins : [ 10, 10 ],
    widget_base_dimensions : [ 140, 140 ],
    serialize_params : function($w, wgd) {
        var data = jQuery.extend({}, $w.data());
        //This will make a _copy_ of *all* data- key-value pairs, including your own.
        delete data.coords;
        //If we don't remove the coords key, we will fall foul of a circular reference
        return data;
        //This will return an array with all the values. The key names will not be formatted.
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I have some problems and I solved this like this

use this on `li`

```
<li data-sizey="10" data-sizex="5" data-col="1" data-row="1" id="55" owner="Minhaj" company="google">
```

And you can use this in serialize function

```
 serialize_params: function ($w, wgd) {
                var class = $w.attr('class');
                var style = $w.attr('style');
                var owner = $w.attr('owner');
                var company = $w.attr('company');
                return {
                    id: $w.prop('id'),
                    row : wgd.row,
                    size_x : wgd.size_x,
                    size_y : wgd.size_y,
                    classes : class,
                    styles : style,
                    owner : owner,
                    company :company
                };
            },
```